# Implement calendar reminder notification in android app

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I'm building a calendar like Android application and I want to add some reminder notifications that would be triggered, for exemple, 1 hour before an event. So multiple notifications would have to be scheduled at different time.

I read some documentation and I see that I could use AlarmManager to do that but it doesn't seems very maintainable. Is it the right way to do it or I need to use something else?

How do I add the notification in my app architecture, Do I create a Service for that? Where do I create the notification channel (I would do it on the `mainActivity` `onCreate` function, but it doesn't seems clean to me), furthermore, is the channel still existing if the app is closed? If not, to trigger a notification we'ld need to wake up the app and recreate a channel?

If you have am example app who's implementing something similar I'ld be glad to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I used to achieve this. I'm not sure if this answers your question

This solution first creates an event within a user's calendar and then notifies the user with a notification some (specified) minutes before the event is supposed to take place.

For adding an event to a user's calendar you can specify the start date and time, end date and time, title of the event and any additional information about the event with a note.

```
fun addEventToCalendar(date: String, time: String, notifyTime: Int = 0, title: String, note: String) {
        // Make sure to which calender you want to add event
        val calID: Long = 1 // primary calendar
        val beginTime = Calendar.getInstance()
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH)
        beginTime.time = simpleDateFormat.parse("$date $time")
        val startMillis = beginTime.timeInMillis
        val endMillis = startMillis + (30 * 60 * 1000) //in this snippet the endtime is 30 minutes after the start time

        val cr = context.contentResolver
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis)
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis)
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title)
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, note)
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID)
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().id)
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1)
        val uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values) //insert the event into the user's calendar here 

        // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
        val eventID = uri!!.lastPathSegment!!.toLong()
        setReminderForEvent(eventID, notifyTime)
}
```

To add a reminder to an event, an EventID is required to identify the exact event you're adding the reminder to. The eventID is contained in the uri that is returned after an event has been added to the user's calendar.

```kotlin
     val uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values) 
        // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
     val eventID = uri!!.lastPathSegment!!.toLong()
```

When adding a reminder, you can specify how many minutes before the event you would like the user to be notified.

In this snippet, notifyTime is used to specify how many minutes before the event you would like to notify the user

```kotlin
 private fun setReminderForEvent(eventID: Long, notifyTime: Int){
        val otherValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, notifyTime)
            put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 0)
            put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID)
            put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT)
        }
        context.contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, otherValues) // outputs a URI
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).